# Merging two dataFrames and drop one afterwards

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames `df_1` `df_2` and they have mutual colmms eg `'Name'`. how ever the names underneath the `'Name'` column may differ, so I merged them into `df` frame and created new several columns out of both of them.

Is it possible to drop `df_2` and keep all the newly created columns and df_1? in no step? one line ? Or  `df_1` with the same columns than `df`

```
df_1 Name Age Sex Jop RoomID 

df_1 Name Age Sex Jop address RoomID

df  Name Age Sex Jop address Fmaily_size  Floor_NR e.g
```

That df_1 looks like this `Name Age Sex Jop address Fmaily_size  Floor_NR e.g` 
Same columns, type and order than `df`.

Comment: Please explain clearly what you mean (i.e., why merge if needed to drop later) which can be done with current results and desired output.

Comment: Simply i used logistic.fit(xtrain, ytrain) where xtrain =some columns of df whereas i want to use logistic.predict(xtest)  where xtest = same columns but with the data from df_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df_1.merge(
    df_2, on='Name', how='outer',
    suffixes=['', '_']
).reindex_axis(df_1.columns.tolist(), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `left` join merge to retain all records from one dataframe (i.e., *df_1*) that match or not with another dataframe (i.e., *df_2*). Unmatched records will result in NaNs for merged columns. Otherwise use the default `inner` which keeps matching records in both frames.

Per your comment --*where xtest = same columns but with the data from df_1*-- below the resulting dataframe, *xtest* are all columns in both frames retaining only *df_1* records:

```
xtest = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='Name', how='left')
# OR xtest = df_1.merge(df_2, on='Name', how='left')
```